# Trapezoidal rule in Python

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I'm trying to implement the trapezoidal rule in Python 2.7.2. I've written the following function:

```
def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s += h * f(a)
    for i in range(1, n):
        s += 2.0 * h * f(a + i*h)
    s += h * f(b)
    return s
```

However, f(lambda x:x**2, 5, 10, 100) returns 583.333 (it's supposed to return 291.667), so clearly there is something wrong with my script. I can't spot it though.

Comment: Probably not coincidentally, 583.333 / 2 = 291.6665.

Comment: Hint: You're returning exactly twice what you should be returning. The [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) formula has a `/ 2` fraction in it. Your code doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

You are off by a factor of two. Indeed, the [Trapezoidal Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Uniform_grid) as taught in math class would use an increment like

```
s += h * (f(a + i*h) + f(a + (i-1)*h))/2.0
```

`(f(a + i*h) + f(a + (i-1)*h))/2.0` is averaging the height of the function at two adjacent points on the grid.

Since every two adjacent trapezoids have a common edge, the formula above requires evaluating the function twice as often as necessary.

A more efficient implementation (closer to what you posted), would combine common terms from adjacent iterations of the `for-loop`:

```
f(a + i*h)/2.0 + f(a + i*h)/2.0 =  f(a + i*h)
```

to arrive at:

```
def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    s = 0.0
    s += f(a)/2.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        s += f(a + i*h)
    s += f(b)/2.0
    return s * h

print( trapezoidal(lambda x:x**2, 5, 10, 100))
```

which yields

```
291.66875
```

Comment: No. You've divided by two twice here (removing the `2.0 *` and adding a `/ 2.0`, and you've forgotten to divide the last term by two, and you're also using the wrong form of the rule.

Comment: He'd have to change more of his code if he did that, though, and it'd be less efficient than what he's doing now because it'd need multiple function evaluations.

Answer (score 4):

The [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) has a big `/2` fraction (each term is `(f(i) + f(i+1))/2`, not `f(i) + f(i+1)`), which you've left out of your code.

You've used the common optimization that treats the first and last pair specially so you can use `2 * f(i)` instead of calculating `f(i)` twice (once as `f(j+1)` and once as `f(i)`), so you have to add the `/ 2` to the loop step and to the special first and last steps:

```
s += h * f(a) / 2.0
for i in range(1, n):
    s += 2.0 * h * f(a + i*h) / 2.0
s += h * f(b) / 2.0
```

You can obviously simplify the loop step by replacing the `2.0 * … / 2.0` with just `…`.

However, even more simply, you can just divide the whole thing by 2 at the end, changing nothing but this line:

```
return s / 2.0
```