# Does this code fulfil its intended purpose?

Tags: python

This is my code for the trapezium rule. I know my code is not efficient, however I was wondering can you see any errors in the code?

Not run time errors, but an actual error in the code. As in would this code actually produce the correct results for the trapezium rule?

After testing the code it produced the anticipated results, however I have been told my code is incorrect which is something I query as I don't see how.

Thanks in anticipation

```
from math import *
def trapeziumrule(f, a, b, n):
  c = float(b - a)# Was getting an error where all my h values would equal 0 so had to make this 
  h = float(c / n)# Then needed to make sure this would give a float too
  z = f(a) + f(b)# my first and last term which do not need to be multiplied by 2
  for each in range(1, n):
      z = z + 2 * f(each * h + a)# creating a loop for my chosen n
  return z * (h / 2)# should produce my answer
```

Comment: I think `c = float(b) - a` would work better. Any rounding errors will occur before the float conversion otherwise. Similar for `c/n`

Comment: `def` needs to be indented in the level of `from math ..`

Answer (score 0):

From: [Trapezoidal rule in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146540/trapezoidal-rule-in-python)
Check the answers on this thread for a better implementation.

Here is a correction that seems to return the proper value.

```
from math import *

def trapeziumrule(f, a, b, n):
  c = float(b - a)
  h = float(c) / n # Change made here
  z = f(a) + f(b)
  for each in range(1, n):
      z = z + 2 * f(each * h + a)# creating a loop for my chosen n
  return z * (h / 2)

print( trapeziumrule(lambda x:x**2, 5, 10, 100))
```